# an error occur in changing the root page

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

i want to set login page as my root page for this app, so i change the code in the app.component.ts like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Error: No component factory found for LoginPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents? Error: No component factory found for LoginPage.

Comment: Are you using lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is key, take a look at your *app.module.ts* and make sure your LoginPage is included in the appropriate sections.

Take a look at the sample [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tutorial/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts) to see where your Page should be referenced.

Pay particular attention to the section: *entryComponents*